# How to write messages to console during compile time in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to write messages to console during compile time?

All need is a statement in my code that writes out static information
while it is processed by the compiler and does not get compiled to javascript.

Comment: Typescript itself doesn't support anything like this, but there's probably other ways to achieve what you want. "Compiling" typescript is sort of a complicated process. Are you using tsc, or Babel, or a packager like webpack? If using a packager your output would get swamped by other output from the packager's process anyway. Can you clarify your use case here and the tools you're using and provide some details about how you want it to work?

Comment: @Alex Wayne I'm using svelte.js and rollup as bundler. Im currently writing a api client wrapper for a api that is not fully implementet yet. That's why im using mocking data in some places and I would like to warn other devs about the temporary state of those endpoints through compiler warnings/messages.

Comment: So when you run a command like `npm run build` that compiles your app, you just want some custom messages to be printed out to the command prompt?

Comment: @AlexWaye Yes. I just hoping that the typescript compiler had such a feature. But I guess finding or writing a preprocessor that looks for something like `// #message 'some message'` should not be too hard.